# how to create documentation for a big python Enum class with mkdocs?

Tags: python, enums, docstring, mkdocs, mkdocs-material

I have a big python enum class with many attributes, and I am wondering how I can generate documentation for it because if I wrote the docstrings for all 100+ attributes it would take a while and then be hard to maintain.

I am currently using [material mkdocs](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/) for my documentation generation with [mkdocstrings](https://github.com/mkdocstrings/mkdocstrings) plugin.

Comment: How is any automatic documentation system supposed to know what each enum value represents? I don't see how you can avoid writing all of the descriptions, unless there's some pattern in them.